# not start internal HTTP server in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-firewall

My Android Studio says:

> not start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and Live Edit May operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart Android Studio

I do not know what should I do, I uninstalled my anti virus but the problem is not gone.

Comment: Firewall settings is NOT the anti-virus

Comment: I know but this problem accurd when i was installing anti virus and i thought maybe firewall setting has changed because of installing anti virus

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio in Iran you should use VPN or proxy .